# Post JSON object to Controller and Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model

I am trying to post a Json string, deserialize it, and then save it to a SQL database using MVC entity framework. Here is my model:

```
[Serializable]
public partial class employee
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string netid { get; set; }
    public string enumber { get; set; }
    public string peoplesoft { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string mi { get; set; }
    public string prefix { get; set; }
    public string suffix { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string tenure_year { get; set; }
    public byte tenure_indicator { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> hire_date { get; set; }
    public string updated_by { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime updated_at { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> birth_date { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ChadAPI.Models.Lookup.employee employee)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.employees.Add(employee);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return new JsonResult() { Data = employee, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };

        }

        return Content("Model State Invalid");
    }
```

And My View:

```
@model ChadAPI.Models.Lookup.employee

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js"></script>

<h2>Create</h2>


<input type="submit" id="Save" value="Save" />

<script>
$(function () {
    $("#Save").click(function () {
        alert("clicked!");
        var employee = {
            id: 77,
            netid: 'caw63231',
            enumber: '00000',
            peoplesoft: '1012481',
            firstname: 'Christian',
            updatedby: 'caw63231',
            createdat: '10/14/2013 3:02:46 PM',
            updatedat: '10/14/2013 3:02:46 PM'
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Employees/Create",
            data: employee,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("success!")
            },
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

When I press the button in the view nothing happens, and using Fiddler I can see that no JSON is passed whatsoever. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does it get to the alert?

Comment: No, not even the clicked alert pops up.

Comment: reference http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js

Comment: See the source of rendered html in browser and check if the jquery is loaded.

Comment: The entire <script> tag is rendered in the page source.

Comment: check it is jquery file not the jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the reference to `JQuery` is correctly set. Jquery intellisense is not the thing!

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I'm at least getting the alerts. However the HTTP error code is 404, how do I know which file it could not find?

Comment: you'll definitely  need a `/` at the beginning of `url`, as follows:

`url: "/Employees/Create"` @Christian

Comment: @Christian, Always use the helper methods so your urls are constructed correctly - `url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Employees")',`

Answer (score 0):

While the script tag might be rendering correctly, if the jQuery(verionwhatever).js isn't loaded you're calling $ without defining it.

Use your browser's debugging tools to see if $ is defined or not, this is a clear indicator that you forgot to load jQuery. Happens to everyone!